# Python socket.create() raises an errno 10061

Tags: python, sockets, connection

When the client tries to connect to the server it always raise an exception. I have disabled Windows firewall and my antivirus and I have also opened the port 50100 on the router configuration panel.

Server:

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 8882

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((HOST, PORT))

s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()

s.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 50100

remote_ip = s.gethostbyname(host)

s.connect((remote_ip, port))

s.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the correct *remote* port in the client (i.e., the same port as the in the server script).

```
# Client
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 8882

remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)

s.connect((remote_ip, port))

s.close()
```